# how to split a column based on a character and append the rest of columns with each split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe:

```
a = [['A','def',2,3],['B|C','xyz|abc',56,3],['X|Y|Z','uiu|oi|kji',65,34],['K','rsq',98,12]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['1', '2','3','4'])
df1
    1   2   3   4
0   A   def 2   3
1   B|C xyz|abc 56  3
2   X|Y|Z   uiu|oi|kji  65  34
3   K   rsq 98  12
```

First, how do I print all the rows that has "|" in column 1? I am trying the following but it prints all rows of the frame:

```
df1[df1[1].str.contains("|")]
```

Second, how do I split the column 1 and column 2 on "|", so that each split in column 1 gets its corresponding split from column 2 and the rest of the data is appended to each split.
For example, I want something like this from df1:

```
    1   2   3   4
0   A   def 2   3
1   B   xyz 56  3
2   C   abc 56  3
3   X   uiu 65  34
4   Y   oi  65  34
5   Z   kji 65  34
6   K   rsq 98  12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom lambda function with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for columns specified in list and then add all another columns in [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
splitter = ['1','2']
cols = df1.columns.difference(splitter)
f = lambda x: x.str.split('|').explode()
df1 = df1[splitter].apply(f).join(df1[cols]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   1    2   3   4
0  A  def   2   3
1  B  xyz  56   3
2  C  abc  56   3
3  X  uiu  65  34
4  Y   oi  65  34
5  Z  kji  65  34
6  K  rsq  98  12
```

For filter by `|` what is special regex character `or` add `regex=False` to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print(df1[df1[1].str.contains("|" regex=False)])
```

Or escape it by `\|`:

```
print(df1[df1[1].str.contains("\|")])
```

Comment: df1[df1[1].str.contains("|")] is this the right way to print all rows having "|" in column 1?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't work. it prints everything

Comment: I would use escape char: `contains("\|")`

Comment: @SaadZaheer - Or use `df1[df1[1].str.contains("|" regex=False)] `